# How to hide back button in navigation bar xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Currently I am facing problem of hiding back button in navigation bar in xamarin forms.

I need to do this in both Android and iOS.

My view image is like below.

[image]

Do I need to write a renderer for this?

Any help really appriciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the NavigationPage.HasBackButton Property in ContentPage to hide the back button.

```
NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
```

[image]

Comment: this is super cool do you know a way to make transparent a page, in the image above you can see there is a overlay behind. I want to see the backing page behind that?

Comment: What is the transparent a page mean? Do you mean you want to transparent Navigation Bar?

Comment: No see the provided image in the above there background view (ash color) is in the top of another view, I need to display that 1st view behind that through the 2nd view.

Comment: Could set this from the code behind as well, using NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);

Comment: What about the Xamarin Android, is it still possible to hide the back arrow?

Answer (score 3):

For my i had to create custom renderer since NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False" didnt worked. Xamarin.Forms > 5
First ShellRenderer

```
public class DriodAppShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    public DriodAppShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override IShellToolbarAppearanceTracker CreateToolbarAppearanceTracker()
    {
        return new MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(this);
    }       
}
```

Then MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker

```
public class MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker : ShellToolbarAppearanceTracker
{
    private readonly IShellContext _context;

    public MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(IShellContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override void ResetAppearance(Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker)
    {
        if (toolbarTracker.CanNavigateBack)
        {
            
            toolbar.SetNavigationIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_back);
        }
    }

    public override void SetAppearance(Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {
       
        if (toolbarTracker.CanNavigateBack)
        {
            toolbar.NavigationIcon = null;
        }
    }
}
```