# Back Button Pressed is not firing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement a function that will be called when user press back button.
Working exactly how i expect in UWP, but the issue is with android.

In android I got two back button,
One at top Navigation (Let's call it navbackbutton ), and other we get at bottom, the three android button "background apps,Home and back button(android backbutton),

Android back button is firing onBackpressed override method but navbackbutton is not, it is just taking me to the previous page.

I dont understand why it is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: It will be great if you can include some code snippet or what you tried to do via code

Comment: the concern is not what  i'm trying to do, the isue wshy override onbackbuttonpresesd is not being called, 
I can include code i dont think that i the issue,  becaues wshile debugging it's not stopping at the break point. that is how i know that func is not being called. but it taking me back to previous  so i  think it might be firing from some place else

Answer (score 2):

[Page.OnBackButtonPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onbackbuttonpressed?view=xamarin-forms) is only triggered with the hardware back button on Android .

[image]

You can override `OnOptionsItemSelected`  within `MainActivity` to hook the navigation  back button event , refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42046133/8187800) .

Another way is that customize `NavigationPage.TitleView`(a layout with a back button and title label) to replace the default navigation bar  and then you can get the back button event .

Comment: Hi , do you have any other questions ? Please consider marking it as answer if it helps.