# How to prevent the user from exiting the application when the user clicks the back button?

Tags: c#, maui

I am writing an application that has several pages. When the user is on the "add page", the opportunity to leave it is provided by the corresponding button. However, if the user presses the physical back button on their device, the application will collapse completely.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="BucketList.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BucketList"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:BucketList.Views"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
    <ShellContent
        Title="BucketList (MVP): v. 0.1"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
    <ShellContent
        Title="Task creation"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:TaskAddingPage}"
        Route="TaskAddingPage" />
    <ShellContent
        Title="Task information"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ShowTaskPage}"
        Route="ShowTaskPage" />
</Shell>
```

How can I prevent the application from closing in such a scenario. For example, so that when you click the back button, the add page simply closes and the main page opens (without closing the entire application).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978276/xamarin-forms-how-to-disable-back-button-in-nav-bar

Comment: Reference https://lukealderton.com/blog/posts/2017/march/xamarin-forms-stopcancel-back-button-event/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of the Android back button is hiding the current application and going to the home screen in the Maui. Because in the native android, it is getting back to the previous activity, but there is only a MainActivity in the Maui project.

So you can override the `OnBackButtonPressed()` in the pages. Such as in the add page:

```
 protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
   {
      Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();// get back to the previous page
      return true; // this will cancel the default behavior
   }
```